# Ensure a parameter is serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

Okay, so let me see if I can make this as concise as possible. I am going to be passing in an `object` of an unknown type into a method that is going to internally use the `BinaryFormatter` to serialize the data it's passed (I chose this because I have no idea what the data is so it's the most abstract mechanism I could imagine). And let's assume that method looks like this **currently**:

```
public void ProvideData(Guid providerKey, ISerializable data, string dataType)...
```

Now let's assume I need to make sure what's passed to me can in fact be serialized and so that why ***I thought*** I would require the object to implement `ISerializable`. However, one issue with this model is that I can't even pass in a `string` because eventhough a `string` is `[Serializable]` it doesn't implement `ISerializable`.

So, what is the proper way to structure this method to ensure that the value passed to me, simple or complex, is serializable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check by using the [IsSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable.aspx) property on the `Type`.

For example:

```
bool canSerialize = myParameter.GetType().IsSerializable;
```

### EDIT BY OP: Final Implemented Method

Below is the final implementation because of this answer (very good answer). It is just a prototype so that's why there's not a lot going on in the method but it proves the answer. One thing to note is that checking for the existence of the `ISerializable` interface holds no value because you won't know until you try and serialize the object whether or not it **should have** implemented `ISerializable` so I was moving down the wrong path there.

Thanks!

```
public void ProvideData(Guid providerKey, object data, string dataType)
{
    if (!data.GetType().IsSerializable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The data passed is not serializable and therefore is not valid.", "data");
    }

    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream("data.dat", FileMode.Create))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fileStream, data);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Easier than pulling the attribute off. Does it cover if the type implements `ISerializable` too?

Comment: +1 It doesn't check for ISerializable but it's more simple than attribute searching (and it perform the check even if all base classes).

Comment: Note that this doesn't guarantee that the object is actually possible to serialize. For example it could be a serializable container with non-serializable objects assigned to one or more of its fields. To be sure an actual instance of something is serializable one has to walk the entire object-graph of all fields in that instance and ensure every one of them is serializable.